# Create custom external pipeline with Gitlab API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I would like to create a custom "external pipeline" through the gitlab api.
Sort of like how an external CI service works, like Jenkins, A pipeline which is initiated by an external service using a webhook, and in the job info links to an external site.

Is there a way to do this? I searched the docs and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1):

Found my solution.
I managed to do this using the commits api's [build status updates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#post-the-build-status-to-a-commit).
`POST /projects/:id/statuses/:sha`